# System hangs, mountall fails

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab, swap

I'm really new to Ubuntu, Please excuse me if my question sounds stupid (also my bad English).

To save disk space, I had formatted my windows installation, and somehow I was able to install Ubuntu once again when the first installed copy of Ubuntu along with the windows start to failed.

My system has 2 hard disks:
1 of 500 GB **which is encrypted**, other one of 160 GB.

**I partitioned and installed Ubuntu on 160GB HDD, then I was mounting the remaining 116GB of that drive and 500 GB on /media.**

When I noticed my system runs without swap memory I tried editing fstab, still it doesn't mount swap partition.

My problem is, **my system get hanged frequently, mostly when I browse using firefox/chromium. The system hangs so badly that I'm not able to get terminal by alt+f2, the only thing work there is Alt+PrtScrn+ REISUB.**

I tried using mountall.

```
mountall: Unable to listen for privateconnections: Failed to bind socket "/com/ubuntu/mountall/server/": Address already in use
mountall: Disconnected from Upstart
```

**Both nginx and Apache are running on my system, I have only 2GB of RAM.**

I don't know where to start to bring my system to working condition.
( I'm stopping my experiments with Ubuntu, whew!!! )

Please advise me, buying an additional RAM or HDD will work here, I'm totally confused and upset that I'm not able to continue my works on this machine.

Update (1):

My system has swap memory:

**sudo fdisk -l**

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   957249089   478624513+  83  Linux

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1        86085632   312580095   113247232   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        61450238    86085631    12317697    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5        78024704    81930239     1952768   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6        61450240    78010367     8280064   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7        81932288    86085631     2076672   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

[image: Disk Utility 160GB]

[image: Disk Utility 500GB]

Update (2):

**sudo blkid**

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="9609fc4c-ece8-4c9b-985e-c1271866aa4c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Ubuntu116GB-OS2" UUID="674b44fc-f619-4ca8-9d07-80a3d43d1b10" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="Ubuntu8.5GB-OS1" UUID="bcd535b5-eef9-4d70-be33-07153802b2ba" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="121099fc-9fa2-4051-9253-b2938c2e7468" TYPE="swap"
```

**sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL**

```
NAME                  FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                               465.8G            
└─sda1                crypto_LUKS 456.5G            
sdb                               149.1G            
├─sdb1                ext4          108G /          Ubuntu116GB-OS2
├─sdb2                                1K            
├─sdb5                              1.9G            
├─sdb6                ext4          7.9G            Ubuntu8.5GB-OS1
└─sdb7                                2G            
  └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) swap            2G [SWAP]
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=674b44fc-f619-4ca8-9d07-80a3d43d1b10 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
#UUID=a36435c9-e579-470a-92fc-e477afd501bc none            swap    sw              0       0

#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=8e474f34-7b1d-49aa-81f1-607192912785 none swap sw 0 0
```

However, I can manually load swap by:

**sudo swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1**

**My system has two Ubuntu installations, I'm running every command now from OS2 which is on 116GB ext4 (Please see image), I would like to delete the OS1 on 8.5GB ext4 and make use of the two swap partition as a single one of 4GB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not enough memory or swap space

With only 2 GiB of main memory and without swap space you're likely to run into problems. I suggest you create and mount a swap partition for that. You can easily set up an [encrypted swap partition with dm-crypt](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/create_an_encrypted_swap_area.html), which will break resuming from suspend-to-disk because of the random one-time volume keys.

To delete "OS1" simply delete that partition with `palimpsest`, `gparted`, `fdisk` or whatever disk partitioning tool you prefer. Do the same for the existing swap partitions to create the larger new one. You can also `swapon` multiple partitions (works with `fstab` too).

### Other possible causes

This could also be broken hardware or a bad driver. Since the issue correlates with web browsing I suspect a RAM module gone bad or a faulty graphics adapter driver, but you should sort out the swap issue first since that seems more problematic.

Comment: thanks to your reply, I was able to figure out there was an additional os installation which works more smoothly. (ie, has more disk space in its root / ). So I would like to keep that, please see my updated question.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to a guide for encrypted swap.